# How to remove substring in makefile

Tags: makefile

Line by line this works in terminal, but not in makefile?

```
test:
    FOO="MACOS" ; \
    FOO=$${FOO//OS/} ; \
    @echo $FOO
```

Expected:

```
make test
MAC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last shell expansion of shell variable `FOO` must be escaped (`$$`). And if you want to suppress the echo of the recipe, put the `@` at the beginning, not in the middle of the recipe.

```
test:
    @FOO="MACOS" ; \
    FOO=$${FOO//OS/} ; \
    echo $$FOO
```

Note that you could also use make variables and functions:

```
FOO := MACOS
FOO := $(patsubst %OS,%,$(FOO))

test:
    @echo '$(FOO)'
```

Comment: Note also: the shell regex syntax `${FOO//OS/}` is not available in standard POSIX shells.  Make will always invoke `/bin/sh` by default.  Some systems link `/bin/sh` to bash so you can use bash-isms by default; other systems install other shells as `/bin/sh`.  So if you continue to use the first form (the shell replacement) you must add `SHELL := /bin/bash` to your makefile to force it to use bash always, else your makefile will not work on systems where `/bin/sh` is not bash.